# Switching php version in wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I want to switch php version in wamp to 7.1

php 7.1 is already installed by default in wamp but wamp uses php5 i cant find where to switch php version in wamp 3.1 in not like older versions where you can switch it from the menu
i have seen all other posts they not the same wamp version there is no php switch menu in version 3.1

[image]

Comment: the WAMP version used in that post is 3.0.1 mine is 3.1 not the same menu

Comment: Same issue here, cant find a solution to this.

Answer (score -1):

Left click on the WAMP logo, rather than right click:

Screens: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSu9B.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkIO6.png)